# Virtual methods using class list C++

Tags: c++, list, inheritance

First of all, excuse me for my bad english.

I'm trying to implement checkers in c++ using inheritance, for this I have set a base class `piece`, and 2 derived classes, `pawn` and `queen`.

I used two lists from the class list, one per player, and in the first version (only with pawns) it worked fine.

But now I changed the `pawn` list to `piece` list and I have some problems.

I call the `pawn` constructor, so the objects are pawns but when I call a method (that is virtual in the `piece` class) it calls the `piece` method!

This is what I have:

**piece.hpp:**

```
virtual int calculardestino(int,tablero*){ cout <<"Not here" << endl;};
```

**pawn.cpp:**

```
int peon::calculardestino(int dir,tablero* B){ cout <<"Yep here is ok" << endl;}
```

**I set the pawn list using this:**

```
listarojo.push_back(peon(i,j,1));
```

**And I try to call the methods in this way:**

```
pos=listarojo.begin();
pos->calculardestino(0,this);
```

But I never get `"Yep here is ok"`, only `"Not here"`.

I have tried to make it pure virtual but I get error on compilation.

Again, sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Can you post code of your classes (headers + implementations)?

Comment: Have you tried [using a debugger](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eEJ5xKO7c3o)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like `listarojo` is a container of `piece` objects; so pushing a `pawn` will *slice* it, converting it to the base class type.

For polymorphism, it will have to contain pointers to `piece`, which you will have to either allocate with `new`, or store somewhere that persists for the lifetime of the list. If you choose to use `new`, then you might want to make them smart pointers, to save the hassle of remembering to delete them.

You can prevent slicing by making the base class *abstract*, so that it can't be instantiated directly. Instead of providing a dummy implementation of functions like `calculardestino`, consider making them *pure virtual*:

```
virtual int calculardestino(int,tablero*) = 0;
```

> I have tried to make it pure virtual but I get error on compilation.

Indeed, that very error is what you want: slicing is prevented, so you get a friendly error rather than unexpected runtime behaviour. Fixing the underlying problem, by storing pointers rather than `piece` objects, will fix that error.

Comment: Thank you all so much. I understand where to problem was, and can solve it correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a list of **pointers** to `piece` objects (and not a list of `piece` objects):

```
list<piece*> listarojo;
listarojo.push_back(new peon(i,j,1));
```

And you will have to delete these objects at a later point in the execution of your program:

```
for (auto ptr=listarojo.begin(); ptr!=listarojo.end(); ptr++)
    delete *ptr;
```